# How do I get Vim Omni Completion working in Makefiles?

Tags: vim, makefile, omnicomplete

I'd like to be able to use Vim omni-completion in Makefiles, so that I can get auto-complete for target dependencies and such.  Anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about omni-completion, but you can use normal completion in Vim.

For example if you have a target called 'installdocs', you can type:

```
ins<C-n>
```

and Vim will complete the target name for you.

Comment: <C-n> will search forward for a matching word, <C-p> will search backwards. See also :help ins-completion